# How to stream random videos in firebase storage with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, video-streaming

I have this app which is a bit like youtube where I want to build random video links, I know how to get a video with a link from firebase but I want it to be random links, Have any ideas ?

Comment: Assuming you have lots of videos in storage and want to get a random link  you can have all links in a list and pick randomly.  

else if you want to generate random links you can use timestamp value to create links

Comment: about the list, I want the user to upload a video to firebase and then other users will be able to see the video so I don't think a list will be helpful.

Comment: about timestamp thing, I acually don't have any experience in it, so if you have a toturial about it, it would be very nice

Comment: I think a json file is better, I upload it and as a user upload a video, I get the link and put it in the json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when uploading to firebase storage

```
string name = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
//sample name 1351441456747
     final StorageReference storageReference =
                      FirebaseStorage().ref().child("posts/$name");
    
                  final StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
                      storageReference.putFile(videofile);
    
                  final StreamSubscription<StorageTaskEvent> streamSubscription =
                      uploadTask.events.listen((event) {
                    // You can use this to notify yourself or your user in any kind of way.
                    // For example: you could use the uploadTask.events stream in a StreamBuilder instead
                    // to show your user what the current status is. In that case, you would not need to cancel any
                    // subscription as StreamBuilder handles this automatically.
                   
                   
                    // Here, every StorageTaskEvent concerning the upload is printed to the logs.
                    print('EVENT ${event.type}');
                  });
    
    // Cancel your subscription when done.
                  await uploadTask.onComplete;
                  streamSubscription.cancel();
                  String videourl =
                      await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
```

and then upload the object to firestore or realtime db

```
  final DocumentReference documentReference =
                  await Firestore.instance.collection("posts").add({
                "postId": "postId",
              });
              String postId = documentReference.documentID;
              Firestore.instance.collection("posts").document(postId).setData({
                "postId": postId,
                "userId": userId,                    
                "videourl": videourl,
                "timestamp" :name,
                
              });
```

now you have your object in the database .During reading this is where you have to sort your data.

example how to show random  videos

get all documents and put them in a list and generate a random number and get object at that index

read more about [firestore operations here](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-9ea80593ca40)

Comment: hey griffins, how would you handle encoding here? the video file that is being uploaded, will it be available in different bitrates?